# How to change "Add to cart" , "Add to wish list" & "Compare this product" button border color upon clicked

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart2.x

In `opencart 2.0.3.1`,

When I click on "Add to cart" button, it's border color is turned to blue. But I want to change this border line in grey color.

I have replaced all the blue color found in `stylesheet.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`. But still I am getting blue color around the  "Add to cart" , "Add to wish list" & "Compare this product" button border, when it is clicked.

Can anyone help, where I can find those settings to customize this border color?

[www.uniool.com](http://uniool.com/)

Thanks.

Comment: what browser are you using? I'm using Chrome on Mac and the borders are grey my end!

Comment: I am also using Chrome. The borders are turned to blue, when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you for your kind information.

I have found all of your information very helpful, although two of you have already deleted your answer!!? I don't understand -why?

I just replaced the following default code:

```
.product-thumb .button-group button:hover {
    color: #444;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
```

with this code:

```
.product-thumb .button-group button:focus {
    color: #444;
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
```

This code just disappear the blue border, although I wanted to change the blue color with grey color.

But disappearing is also OK with me.

Thanks all of you very much for your kind support.

Answer (score -1):

Add to you stylesheets, `outline: none;` to this buttons.

P.S `border: 0` it's for IE borders, sorry for incorrect answer firstly.